# Mixing binary and non-binary features in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I have some binary features (0 or 1) and some non-binary features which have values between 0 and 1 (such as 0.24). I use Weka logistic regression to classify instances with all these features. Does it work properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question of how to efficiently combine categorical and numeric features is an open research question. However, in your case, where you already decided to encode categorical as 0/1 and remaining as x e [0, 1] there is nothing to "worry" about. This is a  valid application of logistic regression. Simply bare in mind that there are no guarantees that this is the best way to represent your data. It **will work**, however some specific weighting can be better, but this is **purely data dependent** property, which cannot be easily answered.